# How do I prevent drawer disposal?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView in a drawer and would like it to only be built one time. I know that it is being disposed because the scroll position resets every time I close & reopen the drawer, e.g., open drawer, scroll to the bottom of list, close drawer, reopen it, and you will see what I mean. How do I make it remember the state?

Here is a minimum working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final europeanCountries = [
    'Albania',
    'Andorra',
    'Armenia',
    'Austria',
    'Azerbaijan',
    'Belarus',
    'Belgium',
    'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
    'Bulgaria',
    'Croatia',
    'Cyprus',
    'Czech Republic',
    'Denmark',
    'Estonia',
    'Finland',
    'France',
    'Georgia',
    'Germany',
    'Greece',
    'Hungary',
    'Iceland',
    'Ireland',
    'Italy',
    'Kazakhstan',
    'Kosovo',
    'Latvia',
    'Liechtenstein',
    'Lithuania',
    'Luxembourg',
    'Macedonia',
    'Malta',
    'Moldova',
    'Monaco',
    'Montenegro',
    'Netherlands',
    'Norway',
    'Poland',
    'Portugal',
    'Romania',
    'Russia',
    'San Marino',
    'Serbia',
    'Slovakia',
    'Slovenia',
    'Spain',
    'Sweden',
    'Switzerland',
    'Turkey',
    'Ukraine',
    'United Kingdom',
    'Vatican City'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: europeanCountries.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(europeanCountries[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is use `PageStorageKey` like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  key: PageStorageKey("my_key"),
  // ...
)
```

Comment: What if it was something other than a listview that was inside the drawer though?

Comment: Like what kind of widget ?