# Can't able to maintain the drawer state in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

- open the navigation drawer
- scroll the drawer contents and then close drawer
- again open the drawer, drawer shows from the top (not maintains
  previously changed state)

Comment: that's how it works. Try checking https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546468/5882307 and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56756325/5882307 solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have achieved this by using PageStorageKey inside the drawer's child:

```
drawer: Drawer(
  child: Column(
    key: const PageStorageKey<String>('pagestore'),
    children: <Widget>[
      ....
    ],
  )
),
```

Comment: you can at least upvote the answer. I see you have accepted your own answer, that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

in the drawer widget, try providing [`PageStorageKey`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorageKey-class.html) as `key` for `ListView`.

It is used by almost all scrolling widgets to store the current offset of the scrollable widget.

you can use it as:

```
Drawer(
  child: ListView.builder(
    key: PageStorageKey('drawer_list_key'),
    //...
  ),
),
```

Comment: isn't we're supposed to prove a link to a duplicate solution instead of re writing the solution?

Comment: If there was a complete answer with `what` and `why` of the solution, I would've done it. But I couldn't find it so I wrote the required description which I would look for in an answer,

Comment: hmm, okay I see, bro ;)